# Using fluentd I would like to add IP address of the machine along with message

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I have fluentd setup in 6 machines, all the machines are sends application logs and syslogs to `elasticsearch`, but i would like to add the IP-address along with the message.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this Awesome link:

http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/apache-add-hostname